# Regex matching question

Tags: ruby, regex

Alright, i promised myself i would learn Regex one day.. but today is not that day.

What is the correct expression for matching `#_` (where _ is any character EXCEPT {)?

---

Clarification:

I am working on a syntax highlighting system for Ruby and i am defining the rules for comments. The specification that the '{' not be included is to differentiate a comment from variables embedded in strings.

Comment: What are you really trying to match?

Comment: did you just want to match just two characters ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You define a character class inside [ ] and negate with ^:

```
[^{] // i.e. a single character that is not {
```

If you add the hash mark in the beginning this results in:

```
#[^{] // i.e. # and then a single character that is not {
```

Comment: at least there is an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

In PCRE syntax, `#[^{]`

Answer (score 4):

This feels like a CS 101 homework question to me.

I suspect the right answer is to actually learn regular expressions today.  What are you trying to match and why?

Answer (score 0):

^#[^{]$

That's my answer if you meant to just match two characters.

Comment: that means a line consisting only of those 2 characters.

Comment: isn't that what he is asking for?

Comment: +1, that's a valid literal interpretation of the question as stated.

Comment: "You are technically correct, the BEST KIND of correct!"  It is a correct but useless answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do syntax highlighting, do yourself a favor and don't try to hack something together with regular expressions.  You'll wind up piling hack on top of hack on top of hack until it's a scattered mess of almost-works and good-enoughs.  Trust me, you'll hate yourself.

Go directly to using [a grammar](http://blog.nicksieger.com/articles/2006/10/27/visualization-of-rubys-grammar).  Either by putting one straight out of the source code or finding an existing grammar on the Internet.